# Autolayout constraints in IB changing when adding a new object to the view

Tags: ios, xcode

Before I start I just want to say that I understand the auto layout constraints to a point where I'm happy to use them in IB and code to create what I want.

The issue I have, which I find very frustrating is that in IB I have a view set up with some labels, images and buttons positioned using auto layout just as I want them, great.

I then realise that I need to add one more label to the view... if I drag a label into that view IB will then add and remove constraints freely within that view to fit this new object. I then have to add all my custom constraints again and remove the ones automatically added.

I just wanted to know if I'm missing something. Is there a way to drag a new object into a view without the existing constraints being ruined, or is this just something that we all have to deal with?

thanks
Stewart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  IB thinks its doing you a favor by placing in the constraints.  You will have to do just as you said.  Frustrating isn't it!